# Deleting multiple empty strings from R list in one go

Tags: r

I have a ***list*** with 65k string entries and I want to delete the ones that have empty strings

So far, I have tried this:

```
for(i in 1:length(dd))
{  
 if(nchar(dd[[i]])==0)
 {
   dd[[i]]<-NULL
 }
}
```

but I had to run it like 5 times in order to get the new matrix, cause I ended up getting subscript out of bounds, due to the fact the length changes after every deletion
Then, I tried this, but to no avail. Any other ideas?

```
for(i in 1:length(dd))
{  
 if(nchar(dd[[i]])==0)
 {
   dd[[i]]<-NULL
   d <- d--;
 }
}
```

EDIT: for the offtopic ruling: I state exactly what I want and what is happening and what the error is. The code I gave actually gives me the error.

Comment: Concerning your edit (seen from review queue): "and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself". You're no giving any clue of what your data looks like. It's impossible to reproduce your problem, specially if your "table" is a dataframe with factors, which may be your root problem. Hence the off topic, no reproduction possible.

Comment: And FYI, you can ask close voters in comments using their names preceded by a @, editing to request reasons is not a correct behavior.

Comment: By the way, the edit on the accepted answer clearly demonstrates the reason why reproducibility is important. You are leaving him guessing as to what your data actually looks like.

Comment: @Tensibai ok, noted and changed it up a bit, but the problem didnt have to do with the type of the table, but with the code im giving. I tried it in datatable AND list, same error.

Comment: How could we guess the type is not the problem ? That's the whole point of giving a [mcve], adding a bunch of data would avoid answers guessing what the root problem is. Using `dput(head(variable_of_your_data))` and pasting its output is usually enough if there's data you expect to be fitered which are not in the head of the data.

Comment: And I had go to something like: `dd[[nchar(dd)==0]] <- NULL` which sounds like what you're after. (with the caveat explained in user127649 's answer with space only entires.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could your 'blank' elements have contained several spaces?

Check this behaviour, the second element of this vector has 4 spaces:

```
x <- c('abc', '    ', 'def')
length(x)
[1] 3

nchar(x)
[1] 3 4 3

nchar(x) == 0
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This last line shows that none of the elements in the vector had 0 characters

If you want to delete such occurrances of whitespace you could have a look at `?trimws`

eg

```
nchar(trimws(x)) == 0
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

You should be able to do this to your whole dataset using something like this

```
lapply(data, function(x){ x[nchar(trimws(x)) == 0] <- NA; x })
```

**Edit**

The answer here will depend on your data. You call it a table, then a matrix. This answer will work best on a dataframe. A matrix will require a minor modification, as will a list

Comment: You should add code that will convert x with blanks (empty strings) to x without blanks as required by the OP.

Comment: @mso - done. Thanks, I am new to contributing, and still making lots of errors :)

Answer (score 1):

You should firstly determine whether the entry is not empty string and then make subset:

```
is_not_empty_string <- sapply(dd, function(x) {x != ""})
dd_no_empty_strings <- dd[is_not_empty_string]
```

Answer (score 1):

If dd is a vector with some empty and some non-empty strings:

```
> dd = c("abc", "def", "   ", "ghi")  
> dd
[1] "abc" "def" "   " "ghi"
```

one can remove empty strings by:

```
> dd[trimws(dd) != ""]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"
```